# Is the input for a linear map $\phi_{\alpha}$ with basis $\alpha$, a coordinate vector which is relative to $\alpha$ or to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a linear map, $\phi_{\alpha}$ which represents the
transformation of space given the basis $\alpha$.

I was under the impression that for $\phi_{\alpha}(\boldsymbol{x})$,
$\boldsymbol{x}$ is relative to the standard basis, and then gets
transformed. I have seen that it is indeed the converse, where $\phi$
takes a coordinate vector relative to $\alpha$, and **then** gets transformed to be relative to the standard basis?

Am I just mixing the change of basis linear map, and a transformation
linear map together?

Comment: Given $\phi: V \to W$, it has many representations for both input and output depending on the choices of bases you make for $V$ AND for $W$.  Without more context for your question, your notation alone does not dictate an answer.

Comment: Consider this context: 
Let $\alpha:v_{1},...,v_{n}$ be a basis of $V$.

$\phi_{\alpha}:\mathbb{F}^{n}\to V$ with $\phi_{\alpha}(x)=\sum_{i}x_{i}v_{i}$ Is this a transformation of space?

Comment: Then they are taking $x \in \mathbb{F}^n$ and using the coordinates of that tuple to give a linear combination in the basis $\alpha$.

Comment: @Randall Ah so this does represent a transformation of space?

Comment: This is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $V$, whatever $V$ is.

Comment: @Randall Why $\Bbb F^n$? There are many other possibilities, aren't there?

Comment: @Arthur  I'm just using the domain that OP gave me.

Comment: @Randall 
Do you agree that for a basis, $\alpha$, the change of basis map,
$\phi_{\alpha}$ is just a specific case of a linear transformation,
where we interpret the same vector space $V$ with bases $\beta$
in terms of $\alpha$ instead?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: @Randall 
And so suppose we have a linear transformation $\psi:\mathbb{F}^{n}\to V$.
Is this equivalent to the change of basis map $\phi_{\alpha}$ where
$\alpha$ is the basis of $V$?

Comment: What is $\psi$?  That matters.  What if $\psi$ were the zero map?  (Change of basis maps are always isomorphisms.)

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is an ordered basis for $V$, the map $\phi_\alpha : \mathbb F^n \to V$ given by $$\phi_\alpha \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$$ is a bijection (for every element in the codomain there is a unique element in the domain that is mapped to it). Now, for $v \in V$, the column vector $x = \phi_\alpha^{-1}(v)$ (that is, $x$ is the unique vector in $\mathbb F^n$ such that $\phi_\alpha(x)=v$) is called the *coordinate vector of $v$ with respect to $\alpha$*.

Note also that if $\beta$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb F^n$, then the coordinate vector of $x \in \mathbb F^n$ with respect to $\beta$ is $x$ itself. So, the answer to your main question is: both, depending on what exactly you mean by "standard basis".